# Работа с компонентом ToolStripComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms

На форме установлена менюшка - компонент MenuStrip, на этом меню создан ToolStripComboBox. По клику на каком-либо элементе коллекции ToolStripComboBox генерируется событие SelectedIndexChanged, отрабатывается какой-то код и свойству Text данного ToolStripComboBox присваивается значение выбранного элемента.

Вопрос: как сделать чтобы по клику отрабатывался код, но свойство Text оставалось неизменным.

Примерно так:

```
/* На форме есть меню MenuStrip с именем: mGlv в ней создан элемент ToolStripComboBox - cmBx */
private void cmBx_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    /* По клику на одном из элементов коллекции срабатывает определённый код
       не важно какой. Далее - имя элемента коллекции cmBx, по которому кликнули
       переходит в заголовок данного cmBx, т.е. cmBx.Text приобретает значение
       имени выбранного элемента, а требуется чтобы заголовок cmBx т.е свойство
       cmBx.Text оставалось неизменным всегда */
}
```

Comment: Сделал такую же форму, поковырял и пришёл к выводу, что единственный способ тут - это по окончании выполнения кода устанавливать свойство cmBx.Text в исходное значение вручную.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос плохо понятен. Приведите пример кода.

Из того, что понял, посоветую дописать строку

```
comboBox1.SelectedItem = null;
```

Или такую:

```
cls.frm2.comboBox1.SelectedText = null;
```

В первом случае снимается выделение с combobox, а во втором просто убирается текст (первый вариант включает в себя второй).